# How to achieve item level permissions on list items

Tags: sharepoint-2010, designer, sharepoint-workflow, infopath2010

I have a requirement where I have 300 Agencies with multiple users and 5 Regions with multiple users and Admins. Multiple agencies report to one region.

When a user login as a agency user and creates a list item and on submission the item has to give permissions to all users related the users agency and the region agency belongs to. This is  mapped using a reference list which agency belongs to a region.

Can permission for groups an item be set using SharePoint Designer workflows dynamically. I was able to get this working if I hardcore the group names in SP designer workflow I am not sure how to pass group names  dynamically to workflow.

The SP groups and their users are already defined in SharePoint permissions.

Comment: Do the users from different regions need to share anything?  If not then why not just create different sub sites for each region and only give access to that sub site to users from that region

Comment: Actually all Agencies under a Region share information in reports. I can't create sub sites.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out solution using InfoPath and SP lists.

First I created a reference list called "Regions" and stopped inheritance on the list added SharePoint groups and users into the groups and on each list item gave list permissions to SP groups that have access to the list item.

In "Survey" list added lookup field from the "Regions" list now when the user adds new item he would see the region and agencies he belongs to.

On the "Survey" list I created folders for "Regions" and "Agencies" and set the folder level permissions similar to "Regions" list.